# CSS transition not working on hovering for boder-radius property

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have some nested divs and `border-radius` is not changing on hover for 2 of the divs. For the other 2 it is changing (the divs not changing are labelled 1 and 2 in the screenshot).

[image]

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong? Also please tell if this is shaping up to be an effective (but minimal) portfolio website for a web developer.

**Please run code snippet in full screen**

```css
.f-container {
  width: 100%;
}

.dv-br-rd-outer {
  width: 30em;
  height: 30em;
  background-color: #47ffd4;
  border-radius: 50% 10% 10% 80% / 95% 40% 70% 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: all 1200ms;
}

.dv-br-rd-in-one {
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  background-color: springgreen;
  border-radius: 80% 15% 10% 70% / 60% 60% 65% 20%;
  ;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: all 3000ms;
}

.dv-br-rd-in-two {
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  border-radius: 60% 10% 60% 80% / 65% 40% 60% 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: all 800ms;
}

.dv-br-rd-in-three {
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  border-radius: 5% 30% 30% 70% / 60% 60% 60% 50%;
  background-color: #ffc107;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: all 1500ms;
}

.dv-text-head {
  padding: 30%;
}

.dv-text-head h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: white;
}

.dv-br-rd-in-two:hover {
  border-radius: 5% 10% 60% 80% / 60% 40% 60% 40%;
}

.dv-br-rd-in-one :hover {
  border-radius: 52% 10% 150% 70% / 9% 4% 75% 70%;
}

.dv-br-rd-in-three:hover {
  border-radius: 50% 15% 30% 20% / 60% 10% 60% 80%;
}

.dv-br-rd-outer :hover {
  border-radius: 60% 10% 60% 80% / 65% 40% 60% 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="f-container">
  <div class="dv-br-rd-outer">
    <div class="dv-br-rd-in-one">
      <div class="dv-br-rd-in-two">
        <div class="dv-br-rd-in-three">
          <div class="dv-text-head">
            <h1>Jamie Vardy</h1>
            <div>
              Web developer | Leicester City fan
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div style="text-align: center;margin-top: 50px;">
      <div style="width: 55%; text-align: left; margin:0 auto;">
        <div style="color: #795548;">tools/frameworks I know</div>
        Angular 8 | Javascript | CSS | HTML
      </div>
      <div style="width: 55%; text-align: left; margin:0 auto; color: #795548; margin-top:10px;">
        <div>github </div>
        <div>download resume </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is that you declared some css rules on `:hover` but two of them have typos.

`.class:hover` -> works.
`.class :hover` -> doesn't work.

**Here**

```css
.dv-br-rd-in-one :hover {
    border-radius: 52% 10% 150% 70% / 9% 4% 75% 70%;
}

.dv-br-rd-outer :hover {
    border-radius: 60% 10% 60% 80% / 65% 40% 60% 40%;
}
```

---

### About your portfolio

I can tell that you are probably self-learning and I can point out a few things to you that could be improved.

- You should never use the attribute style in the html. 
  **Keep your css code in a `.css` file and your html in the `.html` file.**
- Instead of overusing class names, use what is provided to you for selecting items with css. 
  **Use parent ID of items with the** `:nth-child()` **selector.** Read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp).
  e.g: `#parent_id:nth-child(1) { css rules }`
- This one is subjective, but try to name your classes so that anyone that reads your code understand in a glance what is what.
- Do not use divs for every text you want to output.

**Instead of this:**

```html
<div class="dv-text-head">
    <h1>Jamie Vardy</h1>
    <div>
        Web developer | Leicester City fan
    </div>
</div>
```

**Do this:**

```html
<div class="dv-text-head">
    <h1>Jamie Vardy</h1>
    <p> Web developer | Leicester City fan </p>
</div>
```

`<p>` stands for paragraph while `<div>` is more for containing certain elements of the DOM.